# Get Access key from Azure file share - Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a `azure file share` through `terraform` as per this [Example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_share.html), however i would like to get the `Access Key` for this `storage account`. How do i get that, any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't get `azurerm_storage_share` access key since this attribute is not exposed. You need to get the `access key` from `azurerm_storage_account`.

**Code Snippet:**

```
data "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                = "packerimages"
  resource_group_name = "packer-storage"
}

output "storage_account_primary_access_key" {
  value = data.azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
}
```

In Addition, under each component, you can find the attributes that exposed under `Attributes Reference`.

More info can be found [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account.html).